# How do I modify the primary key in database phpmyadmin after deleting a specific row?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, phpmyadmin

The primary key here is generated by the idea of calling the method getRowCount.Now for example  I deleted one specific row using Jbutton ,  the primary key would something like this 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7. Now I want the primary key like this 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6jvB.jpg)

Comment: `UPDATE myTable SET Stud_Patient_Id = Stud_Patient_Id-1 WHERE Stud_Patient_Id > 3`?

Comment: thats the query?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the query below:

```
 UPDATE yout_table_name SET stud_Patient_id= stud_Patient_id-1 WHERE stud_Patient_id >3 AND stud_Patient_id !=1
```

But its a good practice to never change the **id**, **if id is the primary key**